# Show that a subproblem of Sparse Subgraph is $\mathcal {NP}$-Complete

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, decision-problem, polynomial-time-reductions

I want to show that a subproblem of the known, $\mathcal {NP}$-Complete, Sparse Subgraph problem is also $\mathcal {NP}$-Complete.

> **Sparse Subgraph problem**:
>
> Input: Undirected graph $G(V,E)$, two integers $k, l$.
>
> Output: Is there a subset $S \subseteq V$, where $|S| \geq k$, such that there are at most $l$ edges between pairs of vertices in $S$?

My subproblem is the special case where $k=l$:

> **Subproblem of the Sparse Subgraph problem**:
>
> Input: Undirected graph $G(V,E)$, an integer $k$.
>
> Output: Is there a subset $S \subseteq V$, where $|S| \geq k$, such that there are at most $k$ edges between pairs of vertices in $S$?

We can easily show that the first one (Sparse Subgraph) is $\mathcal {NP}$-Complete, by reducing the Independent Set problem to it.

I tried to reduce the Independent Set problem, as well, to the subproblem without success.

**Is there another known $\mathcal {NP}$-Complete problem, which I can reduce to the subproblem?**

Is the assumption, that the subproblem must also be $\mathcal {NP}$-Complete, as it is a special case of the original Sparse Subgraph problem, correct?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi. Please also credit the source from where you got this problem.

Comment: Answer to your second question: The assumption: "that the subproblem must also be NP-Complete, as it is a special case of the original Sparse Subgraph problem" is incorrect!

Comment: Thank you. The problem occurred from a class discussion in my algorithms course.

Answer (score 0):

Let the independent set problem be $\mathsf{IS}$, and the subproblem of the sparse subgraph problem be $\mathsf{SIS}$.

The Independent set problem is hard to approximate within any constant factor (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)#Approximation_algorithms)). It means, it is NP-hard to distinguish between the following instances:

1. **Yes Instances:** The graphs that contain an independent set of size at least $k$
2. **No Instance:** The graphs that do not contain any independent set of size $c \cdot k$ for any constant $c<1$.

Using it, we show NP-hardness of $\mathsf{SIS}$. That is, we show that it is NP-hard to distinguish between the following instances:

1. **Yes Instances:** The graphs that contain a set $S \subseteq V$ of size at least $k$ and with at most $k$ edges in $S$.
2. **No Instance:** The graphs that do not contain a set $S \subseteq V$ of size at least $k$ and with at most $k$ edges in $S$.

**Proof:** (->) If $(G,k)$ is a yes instance of $\mathsf{IS}$ then $(G,k)$ is a yes instance of $\mathsf{SIS}$. It is trivial.

(<-) We have to show that if $(G,k)$ is a no instance of $\mathsf{IS}$ then $(G,k)$ is a no instance of $\mathsf{SIS}$. For the sake of contradiction, assume that $(G,k)$ is a yes instance for  $\mathsf{SIS}$. That is, $G$ contains a set $S \subseteq V$ of size at least $k$ and with at most $k$ edges in $S$. Let there be $m$ edges in $S$. Then, there exists a subset $S' \subseteq S$ of size $t \cdot m$ for $1\leq t \leq 2$, that contains the $m$ edges. Then we make the following claim:

> $S'$ contains an independent set of size at least $m/4$.

The proof of the above claim follows from Theorem 3.14 in this [thesis](https://scholarscompass.vcu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3574&context=etd#page=37). Furthermore, the above claim implies that $S$ contains an independent set of size at least $m/4 + (|S|-|S'|) \geq |S'|/8 + (|S|-|S'|) \geq |S|/8$. That is, $G$ contains an independent set of size $k/8$. It contradicts that $G$ does not have any independent set of size $c \cdot k$ for $c = 1/8$.

Comment: @entechnic Thanks for pointing out the mistakes. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @JohnL. Thanks a lot for pointing out the mistakes. I have fixed them. But $c$ should be $1/8$. I do not understand why you said $c = 1/2$.

Comment: "The independent set problem" "$\mathsf{IS}$" is, by convention, defined as "[the input is an undirected graph and a number k, and the output is a Boolean value: true if the graph contains an independent set of size k, and false otherwise"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)#Finding_independent_sets). The no instance should be $(G,k)$'s such the $G$ does not contain an independent set of size at least $k$". Apparently, you are not talking about the standard $\mathsf{IS}$ in "If $(G,k)$ is a no instance of $\mathsf{IS}$ ". Or are you?

Comment: @JohnL. Yes. You are right. Thanks! I should use a different name for it. I will edit the post when I get time.